# PHP: Slow foreach cycle

Tags: php, performance, foreach, cycle

Following script is very slow - table "users" has about 13.000 rows now. Any ideas how modify it to speed it up? Thanks!

```
<?php

    $first = 0;
    $second = 0;
    $third = 0;
    $fourth = 0;

    foreach ($_SESSION['subordinates'] as $key => $subordinateId) {
        $q1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id=$subordinateId and dogs = 0 and cats = 0"));
        $first = $first  + $q1;

        $q2 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id=$subordinateId and (cats=1 or cats=1)"));
        $second = $second + $q2;

        $q3 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id=$subordinateId and dogs = 0 and cats = 0 and myDate > SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)"));
        $third = $thirth + $q3;   

        $q4 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id=$subordinateId and (dogs = 1 or cats = 1) and myDate > SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)"));
        $fourth = $fourth + $q4;
    } 

    ?>
```

Comment: Make sure the table has proper indexes, you can check by running EXPLAIN on the queries. Move the queries out of the foreach, it seems like you can do this by making an array of the subordinateIds and doing a WHERE IN query. It also seems you can change the queries to one query instead of 4. Remember you can group conditions with () and use AND or OR between to achieve what you have now

Comment: don't use the deprecated `mysql` library, use prepared statements and change your SQL to `SELECT count(id) ...`

Comment: You're doing 4 queries per row, but you can probably combine all of this in a single mysql query.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the PHP loop that's slow, but the MySQL Queries. You could try adding some indexes to your table, like this.

```
CREATE INDEX user_index_on_dogs ON users (dogs);
CREATE INDEX user_index_on_cats ON users (cats);
CREATE INDEX user_index_on_dogs_and_cats ON users (dogs, cats);
CREATE INDEX user_index_on_my_date ON users (myDate);
```

Also you might want to take a look at the [Official MySQL reference about CREATE INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html), or [how mysql uses these indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html).